# JDBC Sqlite rs.next - don't go in rs.next-loop when PreparedStatement has a variable

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

It is really freaking me out. In my code I hand over a generated uuid as my private Key. Now I want to select from a table with only one value inside (avg_distance_as). Everything works fine when I write the statement with a fix uuid. But because I want to get the specific row with my current uuid, I want to put that in my statement too.

soooo no error nothing - he does not even call the syso in the rs.next loop. This one is working:

```
    public int getavgDistanceAs(String uuid) {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");


        statement = con.prepareStatement("Select avg_distance_as, UUID from avg_distance");
        System.out.println(uuid);
        statement.setString(1, uuid);

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getDouble(1));
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this one isn't and it looks PRETTY much the same:

```
statement = con.prepareStatement("Select avg_distance_as, UUID from avg_distance where UUID = ?");
statement.setString(1, uuid);
```

Would be awesome if someone could help :)

Comment: Your statements are completely different. The first one has no `WHERE` clause, so unless the table is empty you'll get a `ResultSet` with rows. Your second statement takes a parameter, so if you don't get results I'd assume you're searching with an `UUID` that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: I'm surprised your first example works, because calling `setString(1, ..) when you don't have a parameter placeholder should throw an `SQLException` (might be a problem with the SQLite JDBC driver though).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - My test of the first PreparedStatement (no WHERE clause) with sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar gave me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the `.setString` statement. The second example works okay, despite what the question says. The issue as stated is not reproducible.

Comment: Sry, I confused you with the mixed statement. To make it clear:

http://pastebin.com/UKzc7NJa#

this on does not go inside the loop - although the uuid is present. Thats my problem.
@MarkRotteveel: you are right - it only worked without the "setString". I just wanted to mention that...

Answer (score -1):

OK - got it... I messed up my order in the calculation. @Kayaman was right: uuid was missing at the time needed.